# NoClassDefFoundError R$string on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a project on Android Studio with this structure:

> Project
>     |-> App
>     |-> Core

Core it's a project created like a library to reuse on the other applications and have this gradle configuration.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.porject.core"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'net.hockeyapp.android:HockeySDK:3.0.+'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.6'
    compile 'org.droidparts:droidparts:2.0.5'
    compile 'com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.12'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:1.7.2'
    compile 'net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner:htmlcleaner:2.2'
    compile 'io.segment.android:analytics:1.2.0@aar'
    compile "com.mixpanel.android:mixpanel-android:4.2.1@aar"
}
```

the app gradle has this configuration:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.app"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions{
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project (':core')
}
```

This compiles and brings all the dependencies, but when I run the app it throws this error

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.project.R$string
>               at com.project.utils.Preferences.getClientId(Preferences.java:178)
>               at com.project.utils.ConfigUtils.findClientResourceId(ConfigUtils.java:68)
>               at com.project.utils.ConfigUtils.getSegmentIOKey(ConfigUtils.java:118)
>               at com.project.utils.EventTracker.onScreenCreate(EventTracker.java:127)
>               at com.project.activity.BaseActivity.onCreate(BaseActivity.java:104)
>               at com.project.app.activity.SplashScreenActivity.onCreate(SplashScreenActivity.java:23)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I did some research and I think the project didn't find the R created on core, maybe I'm missing some configuration on gradle or something.

Thanks for your time and I'm open to any suggestion.
Regards
César

Comment: Hi cersar, did you find any solution for that problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a `settings.gradle` file at the root of your project. The order of items in that file matters. Make sure that you first mention the library project and then the app. In your example `settings.gradle` should look something like this:

```
include ':core', ':app'
```